# replace string with REGEX

Tags: regex, string, jena

I have the following string: `2015-10-14T11:50:34`

Can the *seconds* part be replaced with *00* with REGEX magic?

So I need to get from `2015-10-14T11:50:34` to `2015-10-14T11:50:00`. I can use a `REPLACE()` function which works like this: `REPLACE(string, regex)`. See specification of `REPLACE()` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace).

This yields: `2015-10-14T11:50+02:00`

Comment: The sample information does not provide with the string you say you have. Do you want to change the seconds part only? Or will you have a milliseconds segment as well? And what would you want to do with the millisecond part?

Comment: sorry for providing incomplete information. I dont want to have a milliseconds segment. And yes, I want to change the seconds part only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the great answers.

Sorry, I provided unclear information in my question. Since this is done in a SPARQL query, the solution, which worked for me is as follows:

`(CONCAT(SUBSTR('2015-10-14T11:50:34.583+02:00', 1, 17), '00')`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
([^:]\d\d:\d\d:)\d\d
```

And replace by:

```
${1}00
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/qY7lW1/1)

Explaining:

```
[^:]     # stands for non ':' character
\d       # stands for one digit
:        # stands for ':' character
(..)     # grouping a match
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @FeiYuan. Because there can be milisseconds

Comment: nope, there arent milliseconds. sorry for confusing info.

Comment: @beta Anyways, I think this way you will not have troubles

Comment: @Washington Guedes There is no problem with your regex, I just like simple, if let me choose, I will use this one: `(^\d.*)\d{2}$`

Comment: @FeiYuan. Assuming what #beta said about milisseconds you are right

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax of jena but the regex you need for the replacement is:

```
\d+$
```

It may be something like:

```
replace("2015-10-14T11:50:34", "\d+$", "00")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js for this purpose. It's great library to work with time. 
Example:

```
var result = moment('2015-10-14T11:50:34').format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:00')
```

You can see working example with what you need in here

https://jsfiddle.net/az0cgjac/1/